# Hot reload fails after restarting app with Android back button?

Tags: flutter, dart

Run a Flutter app in debug mode on Android. Press the back button to dismiss the app, then use the task swticher to swtich back to the app. Then do a hot reload.

flutter_tools will throw an exception:

```
 Exception from flutter run: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'NoSuchMethodError' has no instance method '[]'.
    Receiver: Instance of 'NoSuchMethodError'
    Tried calling: []("code")
```

Answer (score 1):

After many try I solve above error by this.

- Fixed this after running `flutter clean`

I hope this is help some one